# Correct substitute in "If america wins this match, it/they will win the series"

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

If I consider it as a team that will win the series collectively as a unit  then we should use   "it" rather "they"

Comment: An online search indicates that both phrases are in widespread use. They mean the same thing. Once you choose to treat the team as singular or plural in this context, be sure to remain consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difference in British and American english. "Team" is a collective noun, that is, a singular noun (team, not team**s**) that refers to more than one entity (multiple player**s**). *In general*, in British English you can use either singular verb forms (or **it** in your example) or plural verb forms (or **they** in your example) depending on if you are referring to the team or the team members. In American English collective nouns nearly always take the singular form, except for sports teams which, with few exceptions, take the plural.

In American English I would certainly say "If America wins the match, **they** will win the series" and I believe this would be the most likely usage in British English a well.

See the wiki articles on [AmE/BrE differences § Subject-verb agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_grammatical_differences#Subject-verb_agreement) and [collective noun § Agreement in different forms of English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun#Agreement_in_different_forms_of_English) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There's no hard-and-fast rule about which one you should use, but someone focusing either on the team as a unit --or on the country itself-- is more likely to choose "it", and someone focusing on the individual team members would be more likely choose "they".